# SQL: how to control contiguous periods of time

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to make a query in this type of table.

[image: table image]

On the right side appears what I want. In query I want rows that contains NIFs with overlapping periods.

I want that if there are one (or more) periods that are overlapped, this NIF who are periods overlapped have to be added to the query.

Comment: You may want to add a tag for the correct RDBMS (Oracle/SQL Server/MySQL/...?). Also, is there a primary key in the table?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: There is something that I can explain better? I have to compare start date of the next row with the period of time of the previous row and I have to see if this start date is contained in the previuous period of time. In this case, I have to insert this row in my query.

Comment: @Dan, I believe we understand what you are looking for, but we don't know what database you are using. Syntax varies by RDBMS, especially when it comes to fun stuff like period overlap/intersect/normlization problems where RDBMS built-in period functionality (like in Teradata) would be very helpful, or Window Functions in nearly any other DB (except like MySQL or Access) may be helpful.

Comment: I am using Oracle. I dont know if I am understanding what you say... I hope yes

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query for this kind of result -

```
SELECT NIF -- use distinct if you want to get distinct NIF value in your result 
  FROM T T1 -- T is your tablename
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
          FROM T T2
         WHERE T1.NIF = T2.NIF
           AND T1."START" BETWEEN T2."START" AND T2."END"
           AND T1.ROWID <> T2.ROWID);
```